# Postman receive cookies with expires: never

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, postman

I use express to create cookie like this

```
res.cookie(user[0].email, token, {expire: new Date(Date.now()) + 1200, httpOnly: true})
```

It works fine when receive cookie from server as well as send cookie in the request. The only problem is that when I open cookies tab in post man it shows the expires is never. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things are wrong here.

- You're not setting the expiry correctly: [the property is named](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) `expires`.
- Using the `+` operator on `Date` doesn't add time, it converts to a string and concatenates a number onto the end, which is not what you want.
- Check your math. JavaScript date units are typically milliseconds. Do you really want this cookie to expire 1200 *milliseconds* (1.2 seconds) after it's set?

This will fix the first two points:

```
res.cookie('abc@d.com', 'foo', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1200), httpOnly: true })
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. It turns out my problem is exactly the + on Date so it keeps failing when I used expires so I tried to use expire which is wrong but showing no error. Also 1200 is just for testing. Thanks again for pointing out my mistakes